# Get a previous element with jquery that is not a direct sibling, parent, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:

```
  <h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>
  <p>Post body text</p>
  <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
  <button>Do stuff</button>

  <h1 class="title">This is a totally different title</h1>
  <p>Post body text</p>
  <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
  <button>Do stuff</button>

  <h1 class="title">and this is another title still</h1>
  <p>Post body text</p>
  <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
  <button>Do stuff</button>
```

What I would like is to have it so that when the user clicks a button, the corresponding title slides down.

So far, I've tried something like (though I've also tried different combos of closest(), parent(), sibling(), etc):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var currentTitle = $(this).????(".title").text();
  $("playerTitleNormallyHidden").slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
});
```

I'm sure this is probably super easy, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var currentTitle = $(this).prevAll(".title").text();
  $("playerTitleNormallyHidden").slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
});
```

`prevAll()` will

> Get all **preceding** siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

**Update**

Since you are using `text()` immediately after `prevAll`, you will want to limit which previous sibling you want. Otherwise, your output will be text from **ALL** the previous `.title` elements.

This can be avoided by modifying our selector using [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) which will get us the first element furthest away from the button

```
var currentTitle = $(this).prevAll(".title:first").text();
```

Comment: `prevAll(...).first()` otherwise you are selecting all of the previous .title elements and text() will combine them all

Comment: @PatrickEvans, very good point. My question is, if you are the fourth button and you do prevAll('.title:first') which .title will it get? The first or the third?

Comment: You will get the third, the elements are arranged closest to furthest, documentation states: ***" the elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling."***

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your accordion body with a `div` and slide Down it.

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>

<div>
    <p>Post body text</p>
    <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
    <button>Do stuff</button>
</div>
 <h1 class="title">This is a totally different title</h1>

<div>
    <p>Post body text</p>
    <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
    <button>Do stuff</button>
</div>
 <h1 class="title">and this is another title still</h1>

<div>
    <p>Post body text</p>
    <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
    <button>Do stuff</button>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').hide();

    $('h1').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $('div').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
    });

});
```

Here is a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kvewx4y3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You'd think you could use `prevAll(".title")`, but that will select *all* the titles above the current element, not the closest one.

Instead, you can use [prevUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) to move up the siblings until you reach the first `.title`, then get the desired element by going one more tag up.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  // var currentTitle = $(this).????(".title").text();
  var currentTitle = $(this).prevUntil(".title").last().prev();

  // Do something with the title
  currentTitle.attr("style","background-color:red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">This is a title</h1>
  <p>Post body text</p>
  <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
  <button>Do stuff</button>

  <h1 class="title">This is a totally different title</h1>
  <p>Post body text</p>
  <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
  <button>Do stuff</button>

  <h1 class="title">and this is another title still</h1>
  <p>Post body text</p>
  <p class="postfooter">Today's date: blah. posted by: blah</p>
  <button>Do stuff</button>
```